# Unable to add Gerrit server to Jenkins, With the Gerrit Trigger plugin, "Connection error : com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail"

Tags: jenkins, gerrit-trigger

I want to add my Gerrit Server to Jenkins by using the Gerrit Trigger plugin. However, When i click the "Test Connection" button i get the error "Connection error : com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail"

I have verified that the Jenkins account can SSH into the Gerrit server without specifying a password, I have also verified that i can open my Gerrit Website from my Jenkins Server.

I dont know why the connection fails, And i haven't been able to find a start to finish guide for adding Gerrit servers in Jenkins.

Comment: Have you correctly filled all Gerrit Connection Settings, including the "SSH Keyfile" and the "SSH Keyfile Password"?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It took me a while to find a guide that included this step. But i solved it by adding the public ssh key in the Gerrit interface. Now the connection succeeds on this step.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have the same issue, can you specify the full steps  you've done to make it work? Thanks!